# Find and Filter by String Value

Tags: excel, vba, filter, find

I am pulling a work organization report and want to find and filter by a unique ID value. The unique ID to be filtered is specified by a public property (this number is used on another occasion so that is why it is public) entered through a text box within a userform.

- User enters unique ID of manager they want to filter under
- Use unique ID to find which manager level column has unique ID
- Move onto the next column if ID is not found
- Once ID is found, Filter column

There are 9 different manager levels I am filtering through, columns AU, AW, AY, BA ,BC, BE, BG, BI, & BK, and they all rest on row 3. Therefore I have columns 'A3:BK3' but am only filtering between 'AU3:BK3' to pull data in the earlier columns.

````
++++++Open File Dialog:

```
Private Sub SelectButton_Click()

Dim SelectedFile As String

    SelectedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()

    SelectedFiletxtbox = SelectedFile

End Sub
```

++++++Public Property Code:

```
Public Property Get OpenFileTxt() As String

    OpenFileTxt = SelectedFiletxtbox.Value

End Property
```

++++++Execution Piece:

```
Private Sub EmailButton_Click()

    'Workbooks.Open OpenFile

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Len(Trim(Me.EnterWWIDtxtbox.Text)) = 0 Then
        Me.EnterWWIDtxtbox.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Must provide a Unique ID"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'WWID = Trim(Me.EnterWWIDtxtbox.Text)

    'Path to be pulled from open file dialog as reports are dynamic
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=OpenFileTxt)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")


    Dim aColumns() As String
    aColumns = Split("AU,AW,AY,BA,BC,BE,BG,BI,BK", ",")

    Dim bFound As Boolean
    bFound = False

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim vColumn As Variant
    For Each vColumn In aColumns
        Set rFound = ws.Columns(vColumn).Find(WWID, , xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            bFound = True
            MsgBox "Found [" & WWID & "] in column " & vColumn
            With ws.Columns(vColumn)
                .AutoFilter 1, rFound.Value

                MsgBox "filtered"
                'Do stuff with the filtered data here

            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next vColumn

    If bFound = False Then MsgBox "Unique ID [" & WWID & "] not found"

'Filter by Region Selected

'Range("AG3").AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:=Region

Unload DistrUserForm

'Open E-Mail

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```
````

Comment: Why is your `Field` value changing? That is relative to the range you're filtering on, so if your range object starts at column AU, then `Field:=1` will be column AU (2 would AV, 3 would be AW, etc).  So I'm guessing you just need to set the Field value to 1 in all cases.

Comment: @tigeravatar the reason is that whenever i just use 1 as the field, it reverts to column A and only filters A. with this happening I was seeking alternatives and I have tried to go 1,2,3,4,5...9 as well and it continues to filter column A

Comment: That's because you're using a single cell.  Define your range clearly: `Range("AU3", Cells(Rows.Count, "AU").End(xlUp)).AutoFilter...` (and also it's a bad idea to use implicit sheet references, better to fully qualify range objects)

Comment: @tigeravatar it is still not working, I am not sure if you have any alternatives for what i am doing.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using the new code provided by your edit. When I create a sample data workbook and fill it with junk, then search for a value in one of the specified columns, it finds and filters properly. When I search for a value that doesn't exist in one of the columns, or a value that doesn't exist at all in the workbook, it shows not found as expected.

Comment: I do see you seem to have additional code that maybe you cut out, there's a commented couple commented lines: `'Filter by Region Selected` and `'Range("AG3").AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:=Region`. Are you filtering again after the loop for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a test workbook for this and filled it with junk data.  I then created a basic userform that only had a textbox (named `txtUniqueID`) and a button (named `CommandButton1`).  Entered the ID I was looking for in the textbox and clicked the button to run the search and filter if found.  Verified it worked as intended.  You should be able to adapt this to your needs.  Here's the full userform code.  Note the `Dim WWID As Variant` at the top outside of the sub since you said that was a public variable (this could also have been in a standard module and instead of `Dim` it would be `Public`, I just did this for ease of testing).

```
Dim WWID As Variant

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If Len(Trim(Me.txtUniqueID.Text)) = 0 Then
        Me.txtUniqueID.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Must provide a Unique ID"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    WWID = Trim(Me.txtUniqueID.Text)

    'Explicitly define your workbook and worksheet where the data is
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim aColumns() As String
    aColumns = Split("AU,AW,AY,BA,BC,BE,BG,BI,BK", ",")

    Dim bFound As Boolean
    bFound = False

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim vColumn As Variant
    For Each vColumn In aColumns
        Set rFound = ws.Columns(vColumn).Find(WWID, , xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            bFound = True
            MsgBox "Found [" & WWID & "] in column " & vColumn
            With ws.Columns(vColumn)
                .AutoFilter 1, rFound.Value

                MsgBox "filtered"
                'Do stuff with the filtered data here

                .AutoFilter 'Remove filter afterwards
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next vColumn

    If bFound = False Then MsgBox "Unique ID [" & WWID & "] not found"

End Sub
```

Comment: You are awesome! I should have stopped being linear with my thinking, but sometimes it is good to ask for help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Question-- If the workbook name is dynamic as I have a 'select file' button along with this userform.. how do i get this to work? I tried activeworkbook.worksheets("sheet1") and it runs into the same problem as I was before.. I also want to refrain from using activeworkbook and to pull the dynamic name to keep continuity

Comment: @AlmondButterJoy Assuming you have the path to the workbook in a variable somewhere, just create a workbook object variable (`Dim wbData as Workbook`) and then set it to the workbook that gets opened based on that path variable: `Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(strWorkbookPath)` and now you can assign the sheet via `Set ws = wbData.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: I am not sure what the problem I am running into. It continues to filter solely column A, yet states the correct column the ID is in and says it filters.. but filters the wrong column. I edited your response above with what I have been working on.

Comment: @AlmondButterJoy I don't think you can edit my posts. Please edit your original question to provide the new code you're using.

Comment: @Sorry i wish I would have saw this, but I can edit your post, which I did. Sorry.

Comment: @AlmondButterJoy Ah, when you edit a post, it's an Edit Suggestion which gets put up for review. I can see what you tried to edit it to. I'll be denying the edit, and I recommend you edit your original question because that doesn't need to go through a review process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205767/discussion-between-almondbutterjoy-and-tigeravatar).